# Who is the father of the flame in Surah Al-Masad

Tags: quran, tafseer

In Yusuf Alis Translation of surah Al-Masad:

> Perish the hands of the *Father of Flame*! Perish he!
>
> No profit to him from all his wealth, and all his gains!
>
> Burnt soon will he be in a Fire of Blazing Flame!
>
> His wife shall carry the (crackling) wood - As fuel!
>
> A twisted rope of palm-leaf fibre round her (own) neck!

Who is the *Father of the Flame* in the surah and why mush he *perish*? And why is his wife cooperating? And why is she hanged? Is this by her own hand?

Comment: Well Father of Flame is a literally translation of the "nickname" Abu Lahab  أبو لهب

Comment: @medi1saif: if I'm reading to correctly, then Abu is 'father', and Lahab 'flame' - or is it the other way around?

Comment: Abu Lahab = Father of Flame because Abu = father of. While Father would be "Ab  أب" or pronounced "Abun" with the tanwyn!

Answer (score 3):

**Abu Lahab** (Father of Flame) is the nick name of **Abdul Uzza ibn Abdul Mutallib**, the Prophet's paternal uncle. He is the first person to have publicly opposed to Prophet. The *surah* references the punishment Allah has in store for Abu Lahab in hell.

When the Prophet first made his message public to the populace of Mecca, a disgruntled Abu Lahab was reported to have blown the dust from his hands and said: "Woe upon the rest of your day! For this you have gathered us?". The first *ayah* of *Surat Al Madad* is a reference to that incident.

He was a very wealthy man, but had used his wealth to oppose the Prophet and hinder his message. Thus the second *ayah*.

Abu Lahab's wife **Umm Jameel bint Harb**, was known to carry thorns to throw on the paths that the Prophet was taking in order to hurt him. Her punishment for that was to carry the fuel for the tormenting fires (the fourth *ayah*), and that she is forever tied from the neck (the fifth *ayah*).

Ten years after that *surah* descended, Abu Lahab died of a disease.

Answer (score 2):

"[ابولهب](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab%C5%AB_Lahab)" is the name of a person (one of the Prophet's uncles).

The verse seems to talk about their situation in the after-life and part of their punishment.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu aleikum,

AS abu lahab was a son of abdul muttalib

so he was uncle of Muhammad (saw) and pegan of arab, most probably he was on his parents religion.
His wife often left firewood on the path of our beloved prophit (saw), and abu lahab threw intestines of pigs over Muhammad (saw). Also abu lahab threw a stone at Muhammad (saw) when he tried to warn the Quraish. Abu lahab had a very red complexion that is why he was called this way. According to scholars, Muhammad (saw) strangled Umm, so she throw no more thorns at him.

Hadith says:
Hadhrat Urwah (May Allah SWT be well pleased with him) says, �Thuwaybah (May Allah SWT be well pleased with him) was a slave of Abu Lahab. Abu Lahab set her free, and she suckled the Holy Prophet (Sallallahu alaihi wa sallam). When Abu Lahab died, someone from his family saw him in a dream, in the worst possible condition. The person asked him, �What did you get?� Abu Lahab said, �After I was separated from you, I did not find any peace, except that because I freed Thuwaybah (May Allah SWT be well pleased with her), I am given a drink through this (i.e. the finger). Verily, my wife is much better of (i.e. in Jannah).

Comment: Please give the source of this hadith you quoted (in the 2nd para), as I've heard a similar hadith but couldn't find the reference.

Comment: Who's wife you mentioned in the last line?

Answer (score -3):

The father of flame is shaitan and his wife is gross sexual misconduct called jezebel. This father must perish so allahs believers can reach the kingdom.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that, then please share it with us? please consider reading http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer